# Trying to Center an Image with text as a banner in SharePoint 2010 using CSS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]My organization recently upgraded from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint 2010, but have not released Designer to users as of yet.

I am using a .css file for formatting banners in the heading of each page, and in control buttons located throughout the site.

Below is a copy of my css and my html file from my SharePoint 2010 site. I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions.

```
/*-------------------   BEGIN CSS  ------------------*/

.bannerlink { 
   position: relative;
   max-width: 600px;
   max-height: 96px;
}


.ban1 { 
   position: absolute;
   width: 550px;
   height: 84px;
   top: 6px;
   text-align: center;  
   line-height: 84px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 32px;
}

/*---------------------   END CSS   -------------------*/

/*---------------------   Begin HTML  ------------------*/

<p align="center">&#160;</p>
<p align="center">

<link title="bannercss" href="/cs/conf/Site%20Components/bannercss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!-- <a href="http://transnet.odot.state.or.us/odot/home/default.aspx" /><IMG style="HEIGHT: 84px; WIDTH: 550px" border=0 src="http://transnet.odot.state.or.us/cs/conf/SiteComponents/Banner.jpg" width=550 height=84></A>&nbsp;&nbsp; -->


</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="bannerlink">
    <img width="550" height="84" alt="ODOT Conferencing Solutions Home Page" src="/cs/conf/SiteComponents/Banner.jpg" border="0"/>
&#160;&#160; <p><font class="ban1">ODOT Conferencing Solutions</font></p>

   </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

/*---------------------   END HTML   -------------------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following CSS:

```
.bannerlink { 
   position: relative;
   text-align:center;
   max-height: 96px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can center the image and text in CSS like below:

```
.bannerlink{
text-align:center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}
```

Hope this can work for you.